# why when enabling timer in c# can't do anything else

Tags: c#, timer

When i Enable The timer while running program، my program will not doing anything else and stop of doing any click i do like exit the program or anything else i am just having this problem in this timer i have another 2 timer when i enable them there is no problem and it is my code on that timer when enable it:

```
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


            bool check = login.remain_AttemptsTime();

            if (check)
            {
                login.reset_afterRestricted();

                timer1.Enabled = false;
                textBox1.Enabled = true;
                textBox2.Enabled = true;
                button1.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {

                timer1.Enabled = true;
                textBox1.Enabled = false;
                textBox2.Enabled = false;
                button1.Enabled = false;

            }

    }
```

Comment: Wich of the 6-12 different timers are you working with? How quickly does it tick?

Comment: @Christopher it tick 100ms

Comment: Make sure this isn't ticking too often. Remember: the value is in **milliseconds**, so an `Interval` property of anything less than 250 is probably overkill and starving your UI thread of CPU time.

Comment: What does the `remain_AttemptsTime()` method look like?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn it is an method for checking command on MySql database

Comment: I suspect it takes nearly 100ms to run (or longer), and blocks the CPU the whole time. This is easily possible, given you need a network round-trip to a database, which in turn is likely pulling the data from a hard disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not yet specified wich timer (there is easily a dozen in .NET), but I am going to asume the WindowsForms one. Also this sounds a lot like a "Programm non-responsive during long running operation" case. Wich means it is time to learn Multitasking.

Only one piece of code can run per thread. WindowsForms (like most GUI environments) is based around the EventQueue. One important rule is that each event must return ASAP. While one event runs, no other code - not even the one used to redraw the UI or the one that aknowledges to windows that inputs have been received - can run.

The WindowsForms timer (and several other Timers) put their events into the event queue. If `login.remain_AttemptsTime()` is long running - for example a database access - the windows forms will become unresponsive until the request returns or timed out. And then you repeat it after 100 ms, so you basically only have inslands of idling in a sea of locked Thread. Such a operation has to be done with some form of Multitasking.

As this is propably your first encounter with Multitasking need, I would advise using the BackgroundWorker for multitzasking. It is horribly outdated and should never be used in production code, but at least in my Professional Opinion there is nothing better to learning Multtiasking then BGW+WindowsForms.